# Azure Traffic Manager for balancing WebApp slots

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

You can create a Traffic Manager Profile, and then add Ednpoints to balance AppService-WebApps (formerly WebSites) as shown here:

[image]

When you select the App Service option you can choose the main WebApp, but how can you select any of its slots enviroments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traffic Manager's 'Web App' endpoints only support the production Web App slot (e.g. myapp.azurewebsites.net).

However, you can use Traffic Manager with a specific slot by using 'External' endpoints.  You can only do this via the ARM API / new portal (the old ASM API does not allow External endpoints to point to Web Apps).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure that in the "Traffic Routing" settings of your Web app.

Go to your Web app and select Settings -> Routing (section) -> Traffic Routing

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to go to each of your slots and add the hostname of your traffic manager to it. As of 3/2/2016, Azure does not do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

External endpoint are invoiced differently. If you are looking for a different solution which doesn't affect your invoice. You can still reach into your slots via the traffic manager using the `?x-ms-routing-name=_slotname_` query string. This generates a cookie entry and redirects all consequent requests to the defined slot, until reset. 
For example you could have a "join test" button and let your users opt in to your beta app by clicking on it:

```
<a href="yourtdomain.trafficmanager.net?x-ms-routing-name=test">Join Test</a>
```

To return to your production slot, you can call the routing name **self**, which refers to the production slot at all times.

In order for this setup to work, you need to have set traffic routing in your web apps behind the traffic managers. These routing entries can be with an assigned 0%, so that traffic is not automatically redirected to them.